# Chesspresso : how can I change the promotion piece?

Tags: java, chess

I'm writing a chess programm in Java with Chesspresso.
Unfortunately, I did not find any way for changing the promotion piece when a pawn reaches the 8th (the first) rank.

I've been searching on google, in the Javadoc index, and on this forum.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never used chesspresso, but I was curious so I had a quick look at the javadoc. Does [`getPawnMove(int, int, boolean, int)`](http://www.chesspresso.org/javadoc/chesspresso/move/Move.html#getPawnMove%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20int%29) not do what you want - the last argument being the promotion piece?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did not look at this method. Now i have to add a bit of code in order to test if the wanted promotion move is legal. If I manage, I'll post my new code from pastebin.

Comment: No problem. Sounds like an interesting project.

Comment: Yes thank you for your last comment :). I've managed !!! Here's the code for a Jframe that lets you choose the promotion piece type for the last move, when the pawn goes to G8 : http://pastebin.com/pAAskdW5. The method is simple : I defined an interface for the client code to define the graphical method in order to get the user piece selection. The code is free (from free). Regards :)

Comment: I had forgotten to include the PromotionListener. That is fixed now :)